# Running Github Actions with label name - only run for latest label added

Tags: github, github-actions

We trigger GH workflows on PRs when labels get added.
For example if you add a label `dev` to the existing PR, it runs the `dev` workflow, but if you add another label - `test`, it will run that second job AS well as any job matching existing label on the PR that has a trigger associated with it (so second time it will run `dev` and `test` jobs).

This is how we check for a match:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - labeled
jobs:
  dev:
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'dev') }}
```

Is there any way that we can consider ONLY the label created as part of that event and ignore existing ones so that they don't end up running all existing matches every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can now use

```
jobs:
  dev:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'dev' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still same result, no @Ben Dubuisson?

It doesn't only take in count the last added label, but all the ones the PR contains too..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).